# sapper webpack warning : 'mode' option has not been set

Tags: webpack, config, sapper

I am not a webpack champion and when I use "npx export sapper" I have this warning

```
    WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/
```

I tried to change the config according to documentation but nothing happens (or I get an error when I try to use CLI...

What should I change to switch to development mode instead of the default production mode ?
Thanks a lot.

This is the webpack config file :

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const config = require("sapper/config/webpack.js");
const pkg = require("./package.json");


// const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV;      <- Original line
const mode = "development";      //        <- my attempt
const dev = mode === "production";

const alias = { svelte: path.resolve("node_modules", "svelte") };
const extensions = [".mjs", ".js", ".json", ".svelte", ".html"];
const mainFields = ["svelte", "module", "browser", "main"];

module.exports = {
      client: {
            entry: config.client.entry(),
            output: config.client.output(),
            resolve: { alias, extensions, mainFields },
            module: {
                  rules: [
                        {
                              test: /\.(svelte|html)$/,
                              use: {
                                    loader: "svelte-loader",
                                    options: {
                                          dev,
                                          hydratable: true,
                                          hotReload: false, // pending https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2377
                                    },
                              },
                        },
                  ],
            },
            mode,
            plugins: [
                  // pending https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2377
                  // dev && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
                  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                        "process.browser": true,
                        "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify(mode),
                  }),
            ].filter(Boolean),
            devtool: dev && "inline-source-map",
      },

      server: {
            entry: config.server.entry(),
            output: config.server.output(),
            target: "node",
            resolve: { alias, extensions, mainFields },
            externals: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).concat("encoding"),
            module: {
                  rules: [
                        {
                              test: /\.(svelte|html)$/,
                              use: {
                                    loader: "svelte-loader",
                                    options: {
                                          css: false,
                                          generate: "ssr",
                                          dev,
                                    },
                              },
                        },
                  ],
            },
            mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
            performance: {
                  hints: false, // it doesn't matter if server.js is large
            },
      },

      serviceworker: {
            entry: config.serviceworker.entry(),
            output: config.serviceworker.output(),
            mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
      },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

In `webpack.config.js`, change all the occurrences of `mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,` for `mode,`. Then set `const mode = 'development'` as you're doing it.

**Long answer**

This is happening because `mode` is inconsistently used for the configurations of client, server and service worker. It is `mode: mode` for client but `mode: process.env.NODE_ENV` for server and service worker. Webpack is complaining that `mode` is not set because `process.env.NODE_ENV` is undefined.

**Optional**

You can also modify your `export` script in `package.json` to be something like

```
  "export": "NODE_ENV='development' sapper export"
```

And then run `npm run export`.